# TortoiseORM: custom queryset

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

In Django ORM, you can write a custom `QuerySet` class for your model and then use that queryset instead of a manager, so that you can then chain filtering methods like so:

```py
Users.objects.active(False).created_before(a_month_ago).delete()
```

Which allows keeping all the knowledge about the structure of the database tables in one place.

Can you do something similar in Tortoise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have found the following approach, which feels a bit hacky:

```py
class EventQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def by_id(self, id) -> Self:
        return self.filter(id=id)

    def by_name(self, name) -> Self:
        return self.filter(name=name)


class EventManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self) -> EventQuerySet:
        return EventQuerySet(Event)


class Event(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    tournament = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Tournament', related_name='events')
    participants = fields.ManyToManyField('models.Team', related_name='event_team')

    objects = EventManager()
```

And now I can chain my filters:

```py
events = await models.Event.objects.by_name("game one").by_id(2)
```